# gethostbyname in c works with gethostbyname("www.google.com") but not with my char *

Tags: c, sockets, gethostbyname

`gethostbyname` works when doing `gethostbyname("www.google.com")` but when doing it like:

```
 char *name = "www.google.com";
 gethostbyname(name);
```

The connection is timing out. I am making sure my string is trimmed before the function to ensure that there is not any funky characters in it. I don't understand the issue.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: `gethostbyname()` is deprecated on most platforms, you should be using `getaddrinfo()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main()
{
    char *name = "www.google.com"; 
    struct hostent* test = gethostbyname(name);
    printf("%s\n", test->h_name);
    return 0;

}
```

is what I tried, and it worked fine:

> www.google.com

Maybe show the code and we can see if the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Well name comes from fgets(name, 255, stdin), I believe the issue is that a "\r" is getting appended to the string

Comment: from `man fgets`: 
>  "If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer."
So yeah, that is probably it, I hope it's fixed then!